# Warring: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, bucle-for

Dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include ('Connections/conexion2.php');

$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];

    $numeroventa=0;
    $re=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from compras order by numeroventa DESC limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
     $query=mysqli_query($con,$re);
            while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($con, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $numeroventa=$f['numeroventa']; 
    }
    if($numeroventa==0){
      $numeroventa=1;
    }else{
      $numeroventa=$numeroventa+1;
    }
    for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo);$i++){
      mysqli_query("UPDATE compras SET (numeroventa, imagen,nombre,precio,cantidad,subtotal) values(
        ".$numeroventa.",
        '".$arreglo[$i]['Imagen']."',
        '".$arreglo[$i]['Nombre']."', 
        '".$arreglo[$i]['Precio']."',
        '".$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']."',
        '".($arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'])."'
        )")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    header("Location: pedidook");
?>
```

Comment: quita esto de tu consulta, ahi no va or die(mysqli_error($con); debes manejar el error de conexión por separado

Comment: Lo quité pero sigue con el mismo error. Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: del mismo modo te indico de donde sale la variable $con?

Comment: <?php
 $server="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $db='carritodecompras';
 $con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password)or die("no se ha podido establecer la conexion");
 $sdb=mysqli_select_db($con, $db)or die("la base de datos no existe");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu función `mysqli_query()`, está función recibe dos valores: La conexión a la base de datos y la consulta. Puedes aprender más sobre esta función [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php).

En tu primera función, `$re=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from compras order by numeroventa DESC limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));` , elimina el `or die` quedando:

```
$re=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from compras order by numeroventa DESC limit 1");
```

En tu segunda función debes hacer lo mismo para que quede sin el `or die`:

```
  mysqli_query("UPDATE compras SET (numeroventa, imagen,nombre,precio,cantidad,subtotal) values(
    ".$numeroventa.",
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Imagen']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Nombre']."', 
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Precio']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']."',
    '".($arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'])."'
    )");
```

Comment: Hola Ferni, gracias por tu colaboración. Hice las modificaciones y efectivamente no me arroja más ese error pero ahora no inserta los campos del arreglo en la tabla compras :(.