# mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una búsqueda de datos mediante el id, y luego que muestren los demás datos.
Después de obtener los datos, guardarlos en un array json e imprimirlos.

A continuación, esto es lo que tengo:

```
<?php

    include_once "conexion1.php";

    if(!empty($_POST)){


        if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
            
        }else{

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            
            //Hago consulta a la base de datos

            $datos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id' ");

            //Guardo el resultado 
            //Linea del error
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$datos) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

            //Guardo los datos en un array

            $array = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

            //Guardo los datos en un json

            $json = $array;

            echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            
        }

    }

?>
```

Alguien puede detectar el error? No comprendo por que dice que los parametros deben ser string, si tengo la variable conexion y la del query.

Comment: tambien estas pasando un arreglo de datos como una consulta ya que `$datos` es un arreglo devuelto por la primera consulta!

Comment: entonces lo que esta en $resultado es lo que esta mal?

Comment: No necesitas ejecutar dos veces `mysqli_query`, la primera vez ya tienes un recurso con los datos, ahora solo lees ese recurso con algún método fetch. Puedes ponerlo así: `$datos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id' "); $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos); echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` Te recomendaría que evites el uso de `die` y que para los errores crees mejor un array con una clave `error` que devolverías con JSON, en un contexto de llamada desde Ajax por ejemplo el `die` no será un JSON y podría romper la lógica en el cliente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warring: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172228/warring-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-2-to-be-string-object-given-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje *`expects parameter 2 to be string`* significa literalmente *se esperaba que el parámetro 2 fuese una cadena (string)*.

El problema es que en esta línea estás pasando como segundo parámetro la variable `$datos`:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$datos) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

El segundo parámetro de `mysqli_query()` debe ser la cadena con la instrucción SQL a ejecutar, lo cual ya hiciste más arriba guardando esa referencia en `$datos` precisamente:

```
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

Ahora lo que correspondería sería leer el recurso, que ya tienes en `$datos`, no invocar de nuevo a `mysqli_query`.

Aparte de eso hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar en tu código:

- Usas `if` de más sin necesidad
- Declaras variables sin necesidad
- Falta coherencia: deberías evitar el uso de `die`, controlando el flujo de errores y guardando una clave `error` en la respuesta. Esto es fundamental en comunicaciones cliente/servidor por ejemplo. Si el cliente espera un JSON y le respondes con un `die` se podría estar rompiendo (o complicando) la lógica en el cliente al manejar la respuesta.

El error inicial y la optimización del código podrían quedar así:

```
<?php
    
    #Variable que usaremos para controlar el flujo
    $json=array();

    /*
        No hace falta verificar dos empty
        Aquí usamos un ternario sólo para ver si el id está
        de por sí, si $_POST está vacío esto lo determinará
    */
    $id=(!empty($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    if($id) {

        #No incluyas archivos sin estar seguro de que vas a usarlos
        include_once "conexion1.php";
        
        #Se supone que esperas una sola fila, por eso pongo LIMIT 1
        if ( $datos=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") ) {
            if ( mysqli_num_rows($datos) > 0 ) {
                #Usamos un método más específico
                $json=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos); 
            } else {
                $json["error"]="No se encontraron filas";
            }
        } else {
            $json["error"]="Error ejecutando la consulta";
        }
    } else {
        $json["error"]="No hay datos en el POST";
    }
    #Imprimimos SIEMPRE un json (coherencia)
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```